# Chrome Extension - setInterval stopping when popup.html closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, parameter-passing, setinterval

I'm trying to build my first simple Chrome Extension and I'm new to Javascript, so I hope you can help me.

My extension has only one goal: creating a Google Rich Notification every X Seconds/Minutes. The Value for X comes from an Input textfield from a popup.html. I'm using the setInterval-Method for repeatedly  creating a notification.

You can see the popup.js and popup.html below.

**popup.js:**

```
var NotOptions = {
    type : "image",
    title: "In die Ferne gucken!",
    message: "Nur auf den Bildschirm zu starren, ist nicht gesund",
    expandedMessage: "",};

var timeElement = document.getElementById("time");
var timeValue = null;
var time = null;
var interval = null;
timeElement.onchange = getTimeValue;

function getTimeValue() {
    timeValue = timeElement.value * 60000;
    localStorage.setItem("timeValue", timeValue);
    activateReminder();
}

function activateReminder() {
    time = localStorage.getItem("timeValue");
    clearInterval(interval);
    if(time >= 3000  && time <= 1800000) {
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            doNotify();         
            console.log("Time is " + time);
        }, parseInt(time));     
    }   
}

function doNotify() {
    var path = "/images/eye127.png";
    var options = null;     
    options = NotOptions;   
    options.iconUrl = path;
    options.priority = 0;
    options.imageUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("/images/tahoe-320x215.png");
    chrome.notifications.create(options);   
}
```

**popupt.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>Watch out!</h1>
    Time in minutes:<input type="text" id="time">   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that it will only work as long as the popup.html stays open. As soon a it gets closed, setInterval stops working.

But when I simply do following code in my popup.js I get a Noticifation every 6 seconds even when popup.html is closed. Here is the problem that I have a fix value for 6 seconds. Instead I want to use the value from the input field.

```
setInterval(function() {
        doNotify();         
        console.log("Time is " + time);
    }, 6000);
```

Now I want to do 2 things:

1. pass value from inputfield from the popup.html to the setInterval-method
2. setInterval should keep running with the value specified in the inputfield even when the popup.html closes

How can I achieve that?

Here link to my github-repo if you want to checkout project

[blink-reminder](https://github.com/chris251190/blink-reminder)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do it is to move the "clock code" to a background page.

This will allow you to run a code without any opened popup.

The popup will only be here to set the number of second between each execution of your clock. For this you can use the local storage like you've done in your code, or use the Messaging API of Chrome Extensions.

If you use local Storage, you can use the `onChanged` event to synchronise the background with the changement of value in the popup.

[Here more informations about background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

[Here more informations about Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

[Here more informations about local storage (onChanged event)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged)

Comment: I added a background.js file where the clock code gets executed, in the popup.js I set the value for the time period. There I execute chrome.runtime.reload();                                                                        so that background.js "notices" the change.  
Is there a "cleaner" way to tell the background.js file that the value for the time period has changed?

Comment: You can add listner on the `onChange` event of the localStorage. It will be raised by any changement of any local storage value, so you have to check if the changed value is your's. I have edtied the answer